# Composite number n such that $\gcd(n-1, \phi(n))$ increases to a record.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

With n prime, $\gcd(n-1, \phi(n)) = n-1$, so I don't list with n prime.
Composite number n such that $\gcd(k-1, \phi(k)) < \gcd(n-1, \phi(n))$ for every composite number $k < n$.
I can't find this list in an OEIS.
My list is (from $4$ to $1000000$): $4, 9, 21, 49, 65, 91, 217, 385, 451, 561, 946, 1729, 3201, 6601, 8911, 25761, 30889, 46657, 88561, 158401, 211141, 238465, 334369, 534061, 851201$ and so on, with the value of $\gcd(n-1, \phi(n))$ are: $1, 2, 4, 6, 16, 18, 36, 48, 50, 80, 105, 432, 640, 1320, 1782, 1840, 3432, 5184, 9840, 10560, 12420, 26496, 55728, 59340, 85120$ and so on. So, what's the next number and what do I miss a number of the list from 4 to 1000000?? I want to have the list with 1000 numbers.

Comment: I think, there is nothing better than brute force. Are you interested in a PARI/GP routine ?

Comment: I note that for Carmichael numbers, which have the form $n=\prod p_i$, it is the case that $(p_i-1)\mid (n-1)$. If you are simply looking for a record (as your title suggests) and not a complete list, take a look at large [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) such as 9746347772161